# ActiveAdmin: How to add sidebar to all show/edit pages of all resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want clean up my code from a recurring piece that I must insert in each resource registration:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SomeResource do
  ...

  sidebar 'Common details', :only => [:show, :edit] do
    div "ID: #{resource.id}"
    div "Created at #{resource.created_at}"
    div "Updated at #{resource.updated_at}"
  end

  ...
end
```

Ideally, I would like to create a helper looks like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SomeResource do
  ...

  common_details_sidebar

  ...
end
```

Or maybe extend show/edit renderer.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Just make partial which will be included into needed View by `'<&= render "ref_to_partial" %>'`.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, here it is - [Partials Tutorial](http://richonrails.com/articles/partials-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is not the best option. I can't use "render" on the registration block. And I'll must add the render method to each show&edit builders.

Comment: No, you can render it once, by including this partial into main layout, application.html.erb

Comment: How I can get attributes of the resource in this case?

Comment: Through Helpers which is available into Views by default.
Get attributes by sending common objects.